# MySQL Delete rows where colum is populated

Tags: mysql

This may sound like a silly request. 
But i have been importing large amounts of data (Over 250,000 lines) 
Somewhere in the data (Between 230,000 - 250,000)
A Quote slipped through the net, and now data that was in 
Column A is in Column B and so on.

So all I wanted to do, was delete this bad data, So I can run various of statements so I can check loading times etc 
(I will be re-doing the import again next week, So I can clean the effected data then)
Just before I do all that, I wanted to check the loading times on the current data.

So in simple, all am after is

```
DELETE FROM rsales
WHERE hour = NOT(EMPTY)

rsales = table

hour = column
```

Records where `Hour = empty` are valid (I have not populated that yet)
Any records where Hour has a value are invalid and need to be removed.

I can delete EMPTY. Just how is the Syntax for MySQL for Populated.

Comment: perhaps `DELETE FROM rsales WHERE hour is not null`

Comment: That just emptied the table :p

Comment: what is the datatype of `hour` ? if its `varchar` then `not null` will get all the values which is not set to null or in other words there is some data in the table for deleting.

Comment: I understand now:
hour varchar(20) latin1_swedish_ci  Yes  NULL

Comment: Try `DELETE FROM rsales WHERE hour <> 'empty'`
But I have to say putting a string `"empty"` instead of `NULL` is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM rsales where (hour >= 0) or (hours <= 0);
```

This will count if there is any value and remove it  (even if it's varchar or int or whatever)